Is there an API for getting the balance of a Wallet Descriptor?
I want to automate the process of getting a balance from a multi-signature wallet within my web application and am looking for a way to derive it from a wallet descriptor. The information I am provided is the descriptor so my current approach is to parse the descriptor, find the public keys and then generate addresses with a gap limit of 20 for those master keys using an API call for each of the keys to find the balance. However that is extremely tedious and I would like to outsource that work to an API.
